# ErrorProvider of the docked Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, errorprovider

How to make errorProvider icon visible if the control is docked or anchored to left-right?
Is it possible to display the icon of the errorProvider outside of the container, which contains docked Control?

Comment: There's no magic here, you'll need to leave room for the icon of course.

Comment: Make a custom control and use that